# Read from Agilent 34970A

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm new with C# and I want to read thermocouples type T from an Agilent 34970A, using RS232.
In Labview I had no problem to achieve it, but with C# I just can't figure how to do it.
Before I continue explaining I just want to clarify that I have all dll, libraries, and SW required to read data from the DMM.

In the official web I can't find an example that helps me to learn how to communicate with the device.
Can someone help me? I just want a little example showing how to connect with the device (RS-232), setting parameters and then asking for the temperature in one of the channels.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at `SerialPort` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You need to post a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried, and be specific about where your knowledge gaps are.   This is not so much a programming question as it is asking someone to commit their time do your work for you.

Comment: Yes.  Been using 34980A for 10 years with GBIP.  I done lots of RS232 over the years.  Recommend using Asynchronous mode.